# eclipse xtext: How can I know if file contain errors

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, xtext

I am implementing an Eclipse plugin in Java. I want to write a function that for a given path to a file (such as `file.myDSL`) returns whether the file has errors or it's a legal file.

Comment: This needs more context: are you writing an Eclipse plugin or some other kind of Java application in which you've embedded XText?

Comment: I used Xtext to develop a language (let's say MyDSL). Now I develop a new plugin that gets someFile.mydsl path as an input, and it should return if this file has errors, So this new plugin first needs to run the Xtext plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IProject theProject = 
ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("theProject");
theProject.build(...); // or whatever operation to make sure Xtext checked the file
IFile theFile = project.getFile("file.myDsl");
theFile.getMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_ZERO);
```

Comment: How can I distinguish between a warning and an error in the IMarker object?

Comment: `marker.getAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY) == IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR`